# Show that $ 2 \sinh(z)=\exp(z)-\exp(-z)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, hyperbolic-functions

$ 2 \sinh(z)=\exp(z)-\exp(-z)$;

$ 2 \cosh(z)=\exp(z)+\exp(-z)$

where $z \in \mathbb{C} $

$$\sin(z) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1!} z^{2k+1}$$

$$\cos(z) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k!} z^{2k}$$

I guess that I have to use a trigonometrical identity, but I don't know which one and is that step equivalent to use it for hyperbolic functions?
Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your definition of $\operatorname{sinh}(z)$? For the second identity it should be $\exp(z)+\exp(-z)$

Comment: Yes I have corrected the mistake

Comment: Do you define, for example, $\sinh z:=-i\sin iz$?

Comment: @Herrpeter: What is your definition of hyperbolic trigonometric functions? There are multiple equivalent ways to define them (such as infinite series, solutions to a second order differential equation, functional equations, inverse function of a certain integral, parametrization of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$, and possibly more), and what you are trying to prove is actually one of the definitions.

Comment: You have defined you $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$, but how do you define the relationship between the hyperbolic and regular trig functions? Is it (for example) $\sinh(z)=-i\sin(iz)$ and $\cosh(z)=\cos(iz)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to answer this question without knowing what definitions you are using for your functions. However, if you use the series expansions, then

$$\exp(z)-\exp(-z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{z^n}{n!}(1-(-1)^n)\right]$$

Note that at even $n$ the expression in the brackets is $0$ and at odd $n$ it is $2\frac{z^n}{n!}$. Then the expression simplifies to

$$=2\sum_{n\text{ odd}}^\infty \frac{z^{n}}{n!}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=2\sinh(z)$$

You can do a similar manipulation to get the identity involving $\cosh(z)$. Again, I want to emphasize that this method only works if you have previously shown that these functions have these series expansions. Without knowing how you define the functions, this is one possible way to show the identities in question.

Comment: Sorry, I could send only now the definition $$sin(z) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1!} z^{2k+1}$$

$$cos(z) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k!} z^{2k}$$

Comment: @Herrpeter But how are you defining the hyperbolic functions?